# NumPy: Evaulate index array during vectorized assignment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I would like to vectorize this NumPy operation:

```
for j in range(yt):
    for i in range(xt):
        y[j, i] = x[idx[j, i], j, i]
```

where `idx` contains axis-0 index to an `x` slice. Is there some simple way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
J, I = np.ogrid[:yt, :xt]
x[idx, J, I]
```

Here is the test:

```
import numpy as np

yt, xt = 3, 5
x = np.random.rand(10, 6, 7)
y = np.zeros((yt, xt))
idx = np.random.randint(0, 10, (yt, xt))

for j in range(yt):
    for i in range(xt):
        y[j, i] = x[idx[j, i], j, i]

J, I = np.ogrid[:yt, :xt]
np.all(x[idx, J, I] == y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using [`linear indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) -

```
zt,yt,xt = x.shape
out = x.reshape(zt,-1)[idx.ravel(),np.arange(yt*xt)].reshape(-1,xt)
```

---

**Runtime tests & verify output**

This section compares the proposed approach in this post and the [`other orgid based solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24154672/3293881) on performance and also verifies the outputs.

Function definitions -

```
def original_app(x,idx):
    _,yt,xt = x.shape
    y = np.zeros((yt,xt))
    for j in range(yt):
        for i in range(xt):
            y[j, i] = x[idx[j, i], j, i]
    return y

def ogrid_based(x,idx):
    _,yt,xt = x.shape
    J, I = np.ogrid[:yt, :xt]
    return x[idx, J, I]

def reshape_based(x,idx):                               
    zt,yt,xt = x.shape
    return x.reshape(zt,-1)[idx.ravel(),np.arange(yt*xt)].reshape(-1,xt)
```

Setup inputs -

```
In [56]: # Inputs
    ...: zt,yt,xt = 100,100,100
    ...: x = np.random.rand(zt,yt,xt)
    ...: idx = np.random.randint(0,zt,(yt,xt))
...:
```

Verify outputs -

```
In [57]: np.allclose(original_app(x,idx),ogrid_based(x,idx))
Out[57]: True

In [58]: np.allclose(original_app(x,idx),reshape_based(x,idx))
Out[58]: True
```

Timings -

```
In [68]: %timeit original_app(x,idx)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.97 ms per loop

In [69]: %timeit ogrid_based(x,idx)
1000 loops, best of 3: 391 µs per loop

In [70]: %timeit reshape_based(x,idx)
1000 loops, best of 3: 230 µs per loop
```